# At most k adjacent 1s (Maximum Value limited neighbors)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

In my algorithms course, there's a question in the book that goes as follows: "You are given an array a[1..n] of positive numbers and an integer k. You have to produce an array b[1..n], such that: for each j, b[j] is either 1 or 0. Array b has adjacent 1s at most K times. Sum(a[j]*b[j]) for 1 <= j <= n is maximized." For example given an array [10, 100, 300, 400, 50, 4500, 200, 30, 90] and k = 2 the array b can be = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] which maximizes the sum to 5500.

The solution uses Dynamic programing when discussing this with some friends they said the recurrence relation is of the form M(i, j) = max(M(i-2, j) + a[i], M(i-1, j-1) + a[i])

can someone explain why so? or if they have a different form of solving such a problem. I find Dynamic programing a bit hard to grasp. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M[i, j] is max sum from 1 to i, with j adjacent 1s

M[i,j] can be computed as the max of 3 situations:

```
b[i]=0  =>  S=M[i-1, j]   // a[i] not added to sum, b[1..i-1] has same number of adjacent 1s (j) as b[1..i] because b[i] is zero

b[i]=1 and b[i-1]=0  => S=M[i-2, j]+a[i]   // a[i] added to sum, b[1..i-2] has same number of adjacencent 1s, because b[i-1] is zero

b[i]=1 and b[i-1]=1  => S=M[i-1, j-1]+a[i]   // a[i] added to sum, since b[i] and b[i-1] are both 1, they count as adjacent 1s, so b[1..i-1] contains only j-1 adjacent 1s
```

The recursive rule is the max of the 3 sums above.
The end condition is M[1, j]=a[1] because b[1..1] has only one item b[1]=1 and no adjacent 1s.

The answer we need is M[n, k].

Complexity is O(nk).

Comment: ATTENTION !!!!  Juan Lopez answer above is wrong - try to run print solve([100,100,1,100],1) and you will get [0, 1, 0, 1] instead of [1,1,0,1] .   Why do you post wrong answer AFTER i already posted correct answer ? It's advisable to read the existing answers first.    P.S.  capitalization is for types and classes, not variables !  it's a universally accepted convention.

Comment: No, it is not. solve([100,100,1,100],1) means there cannot be more than 1 adjacent "1"s. So [1, 1, 0, 1] isn't a valid answer. And I posted my answer exactly because I think your answer is incorrect. Also, don't harass other posters just because you posted first.

Comment: print solve([10, 100, 300, 400, 50, 4500, 200, 30, 90], 2) outputs  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]   which contains two adjacent pairs !!!  similarly  [1,1,0,1] has exactly 1 adjacent pair, which is what I asked for.

Comment: I think that's not what the question is really asking. We need more OP examples to be sure. Or just let the OP decide. But it's not ok to edit someone else's answer if you disagree with it. Please note that I didn't even downvote your answer.

Comment: well your own code returns [1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1] for the original example, which is correct because it contains two adjacent pairs of consecutive 1s.  It's just that your code gives the wrong answer for arr=[100,100,1,100] and k=2, because it ignores the recursive case of M[i-2, j]+a[i].

Comment: My code returns [1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1] because it contains at most a 2 adjacent "1"s , not because it contains 2 instances of adjacent "1"s.

Comment: i see, so you're treating the word "adjacent" to mean "consecutive", so for the original input array and k=3 your code returns [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], which is correct under your (questionable) interpretation of the question.

Comment: Just to clear things out gen-y-s is right about the adjacency. It's not concerned about the consecutiveness. And regarding the recurrence relation, when you say a[i] = 0 do you mean the array b[i]?

Comment: @Athoug ok, removing my answer. Please consider ticking this answer as correct if it answers you question.

Comment: the complexity is O(NK) . Well we can do it in O(N) using F(N)=max(Sum from N to N-K + F(N-K-1),F(N-1)). Seriously who is upvoting this?